# how to change multiplines in a file using re.match()

Tags: python

I have four words in the input file (`input.txt`) and I want to search those words in the another input file (`file.txt`). If the word matches the conditions, the fourth column of the `file.txt` will be multiplied by 2. My code writes the data to the output file (`file_edited.txt`) 4 times. This isn't what I want. How can I fix my code?

**My code:**

```
# !/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import re
import numpy as np

out = open("file_edited.txt", "w")
with open("input.txt", mode='r') as f:
    for lines in f:
        line = lines.strip()

        search_str = line    
        with open('file.txt', mode='r') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                data = line.rstrip().split()
                if (len(data) == 4) and re.match(search_str, line):
                  data[3] = 2 * float(data[3])
                  out.write("%s %5s %12s %7.2f\n" % (data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]))
                else:
                    out.write(line)
out.close()
```

**input.txt**

```
C48D42
CC3752
A52C35
A4814C
```

**file.txt:**

```
C1522      1    07.123222    1.98  1.222222 
C48D42     9    08.222222    2.13
C48D42     4    07.288822    5.58  5.356359
CC3D51     2    09.227822    2.58  3.568523
CC3752     3    07.333333    4.45
ABCD15     3    07.266222    2.50  5.084582 
CC3752     6    07.222222    3.25  4.084582  
CC3552     3    07.223222    8.42  8.356359
A52C35     3    09.222222    2.15
A4814C     3    07.222222    2.55  5.256254
A4814C     3    07.222222    3.45
CCD152     3    07.222222    0.00  2.451678
```

**Desired output (file_edited.txt):**

```
C1522      1    07.123222    1.98  1.222222 
C48D42     9    08.222222    4.26
C48D42     4    07.288822    5.58  5.356359
CC3D51     2    09.227822    2.58  3.568523
CC3752     3    07.333333    8.90
ABCD15     3    07.266222    2.50  5.084582 
CC3752     6    07.222222    3.25  4.084582  
CC3552     3    07.223222    8.42  8.356359
A52C35     3    09.222222    4.30
A4814C     3    07.222222    2.55  5.256254
A4814C     3    07.222222    6.90
CCD152     3    07.222222    0.00  2.451678
```

Comment: why not load file.txt as csv and do operation on that  ?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Can you explain the operation you're trying to perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you iterate over input, in the second loop you write all lines again. Try store info in a data struct as a defaultdict.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import re
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

# Create a data structure to keep track of values
d = defaultdict(str)

# Here you initialize all default values
# because you just replace what you need
with open('file.txt', mode='r') as infile:
    for index, line in enumerate(infile):
        d[index] = line

out = open("file_edited.txt", "w")
with open("input.txt", mode='r') as f:
    for lines in f:
        line = lines.strip()

        search_str = line
        with open('file.txt', mode='r') as infile:
            for index, line in enumerate(infile):
                data = line.rstrip().split()
                if (len(data) == 4) and re.match(search_str, line):
                    data[3] = 2 * float(data[3])
                    # Now you just replace the value if you really need
                    # If you do not replace the value it will be the default already initialized
                    d[index] = "%s %5s %12s %7.2f\n" % (data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3])

# Now you just print the values to file without repeat them
for k, v in d.items():
    out.write(v)

out.close()
```